# Generating Websphere 7 stubs with Maven 2

Tags: maven, maven-2, websphere, stubs

Does anyone know how to generate the rmi stubs for websphere 7 using Maven 2?  I have found a websphere 6 maven plugin, but not sure that it would be compatible and it is quite old.